# Is there a way to create a "rounded" vuetify outlined text-field in vuetify@3 with vite setup?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I have this simple example.
First, initialized a vue project with `npm install vue@latest` (vue@3).
Then, install vuetify@^3.1.11.
Then add this text field to your code after including vuetify in your project.

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="modelValue"
  variant="outlined"
  rounded
  ></v-text-field>
```

This should show on the UI an input field with border-radius. But doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you're looking at the [Vuetify 2 documentation](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props) that lists a `rounded` prop.  The [Vuetify 3 documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/) for the same component does not list a `rounded` prop indicating it's no longer supported.  If you want to change the border-radius you'll need to apply your own CSS

Answer (score 0):

Border of outlined v-text-field is set up on two elements `.v-field__outline__start, .v-field__outline__end`. The first one has too small width for being rounded with big radius, so my solution for setting rounded border is:

1. Remove border from this two elements
2. Set necessary border and border-radius (in my case it was necessary to reproduce rounded-pill behavior) on parent element which is `.v-field__outline`
   In my case I use scss, so component I added below code into component styles

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
:deep(.v-field__outline) {
  border: 1px solid #F6FDEB;
  border-radius: 999px !important;

  .v-field__outline__start,
  .v-field__outline__end {
    border: none !important;
  }
}
</style>
```

The final result is on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvAkG.png)